How to use the same SHA-1 key for Firebase and Google Play Console?
I’m trying to ensure that the SHA-1 key used in Firebase matches the one used in the Google Play Console for app signing. After uploading my release keystore’s SHA-1 to Firebase and signing the app for release, the Play Console generated a new SHA-1 key. This mismatch is causing issues with Firebase services like authentication and analytics. I need help understanding how to sync these keys or update Firebase/Play Console to use the same SHA-1 key without breaking app functionality.
I'm working on a Flutter app, and I need to ensure that the same SHA-1 key is used for both Firebase and the Google Play Console. Here are the details:

I've generated a release keystore and added its SHA-1 to Firebase for authentication purposes.

I uploaded the output.zip (created using the PEPK tool) to the Play Console for signing.

Firebase seems to require the SHA-1 key from my original keystore, while Play Console uses a new key generated after uploading output.zip.


How can I ensure both platforms (Firebase and Play Console) use the same SHA-1 key? Is there a way to synchronize the keys or an alternative setup for this?

To add the Play Console's SHA-1 Key to Firebase for your Android app, follow these steps:
Step 1: Retrieve the SHA-1 Key from Play Console

Go to the Google Play Console.
Select your app
Navigate to Setup > App Signing.
Scroll down to App signing key certificate
Copy SHA-1 certificate fingerprint
Paste it to firebase

Step 2: Add the SHA-1 Key to Firebase

Open your Firebase project in the Firebase Console.
Navigate to Project Settings > Your apps.
Select your Android app and scroll to the SHA certificate fingerprints section.
Add the SHA-1 key from the Play Console.
Keep both SHA-1 key for debug and release mode

Step 3: Rebuild and Redeploy the App

After adding the SHA-1 key to Firebase, rebuild your app and redeploy it to ensure the changes take effect.

This will allow Firebase services like authentication and cloud messaging to work correctly with your Play Store app.
If you encounter any issues, make sure you’ve added both the debug and release SHA-1 keys in Firebase.

You may note that when uploading an apk/aab signed with KeyA (your key, the same key you're using for firebase, also called upload key), then Google sign your app with the auto-generated key (KeyB, also called signing key) before distributing to user.

So you must add KeyB to your firebase too (go Play dashboard -> app signing -> you'll find out KeyB) to make feature work correctly
If you would like to use the same key, you can choose not to opt in to Play App Signing (but only for apps created before August 2021), more details here

